# Is it possible to determine if the data being sent back from an activity is a String or String[]?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I am launching an `activityForResult()` from my `MainActivity`. Depending one the option the user selects in the `SecondActivity` it returns either a `String` or a `String[]`. In my `MainActivity` I override `onActivityResult()`, but how can I test the returned data first to see if it's a `String` or `String[]` so I can handle it accordingly?

This is how I'm handling the Array:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    String[] result =data.getStringArrayExtra("elements");
                    et.setText("");
                    for(int i=0;i<result.length;i++){
                        et.append(result[i].toString());
            }
            }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not always return a `String[]` from the `SecondActivity`? If there is only a single `String`, simply return a `String []` with that one `String` in it. This seems like bad design to return two different types of objects with the same key...

Answer (score 1):

I would put those in  different key.
Something like `element` to the `String`, and `elements` to a `String[]`.

```
String[] result =data.getStringArrayExtra("elements");
if(result == null)
   String strResult = data.getStringExtra("element");
```

I also supports what Steven said. But don't know the design of your app and the reason you do it like that, so you have to make the choice.

Answer (score 0):

You almost did that.. just check

```
if(result != null)
   // it is array
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers. Steven you made an excellent point. Thanks. Going to accept your answer but I have to wait 5 more mins :)